# How do I keep my items in asp:dropdownlist after !Page.IsPostBack?

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I am loading a list of value/text into a asp:dropdownlist by calling a stored procedure. I populate the dropdownlist on the PageLoad method inside a !Page.IsPostBack block like so:

```
if (!Page.IsPostBack)
{
     GetDropDownLists();
     DataBind();
}
```

And this is my code implementation for the backend:

```
protected void GetDropDownLists()
{
     DataTable dt = new DataTable();

     SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connString);
     SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("get_articletype", conn);
     cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
     SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
               
     adapter.Fill(dt);
     xArticleTypeList.Items.Clear();
     xArticleTypeList.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("- Select.. -", "0"));
     xArticleTypeList.SelectedIndex = 0;
     xArticleTypeList.DataSource = dt;
     xArticleTypeList.DataValueField = "TypeValue";
     xArticleTypeList.DataTextField = "TypeName";
     xArticleTypeList.DataBind();
}
```

If my code isn't inside a !Page.IsPostBack block, after I click my save button the default value will always be the first item of the dropdownlist. But once I put my code inside the !Page.IsPostBack block my dropdownlist is empty. For reference here is the frontend implementation of my asp:dropdownlist.

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="xArticleTypeList" EnableViewState="true" AutoPostBack="true" CssClass="form-control" runat="server" />
```

I understand that there are other topics that cover this question, but none of the proposed solutions worked for me. Thanks you in advance for your inputs.

Comment: Do you really need `AutoPostBack` `true`?

Comment: I copy/pasted my line from some template is why I had it. Even with by taking that part out it doesn't fix my issue.

Comment: Check view state for page or master page is not set false

Comment: I've already checked, neither the master page or the current page this code is on has the view state set to false.

Comment: `default value will always be the first item of the dropdownlist.` and `my dropdownlist is empty` where do you check this?

Comment: Logic of method `DataBind()` does anything with the ddl?

Comment: @Chetan - When I run my code and check the database where my data is stored, the default value is always the first item of my ddl no matter which value I pick. But that is only if I don't insert my GetDropDownList() method inside the Postback clause . If I do insert it inside my Postback clause the ddl is completely empty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that you inserting the blank please select row BEFORE you bind. As a result, when you bind, you are blowing out the drop down.

Try it this way:

```
   protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
            LoadData();
    }


    void LoadData()
    {
        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(Properties.Settings.Default.TEST4))
        {
            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("get_articletype", conn))
            {
                DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                conn.Open();
                dt.Load(cmd.ExecuteReader());

                xArticleTypeList.DataSource = dt;
                xArticleTypeList.DataValueField = "TypeValue";
                xArticleTypeList.DataTextField = "TypeName";
                xArticleTypeList.DataBind();

                xArticleTypeList.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("- Select.. -", "0"));
            }
        }
    }
```

And GET RID of your extra call re-bind You have this:

```
 GetDropDownLists();
 DataBind();   <--- remove unless you need, or execute BEFORE the GetDropDownList()
```

So move your add/insert blank row to the drop down to AFTER the drop down data bind.

And REMOVE your DataBind() - you don't need it, and if for some reason you do, then move the DataBind() to before your load of the GetDropDownLists() - but my guess is that you just tossed that in the hope of making this work, and it going to cause the combo box to re-select - so remove unless you give a REALL GOOD HIGH quality outline and narrative as to why you have the DataBin() command there - (but as as noted, if you really, but really really do need to execute that DataBind() command - move it to before the load of the combo).

So, add the blank row after

Comment: Your answer helped me figure out what I was doing wrong - I should have added that in my code, in order to get to the ddl I had to click on a button that activates a hidden panel after the page had eventually loaded. But that made me realize that by setting the visibility of my hidden panel from false to true, the page reloads and  lose all my data. Also you were right about my blank select item. Since your answer lead me to find my error, I'm voting your answer as a solution. Thank you!

Comment: Keep also in mind that often better to use  style="display:none" or style = "display:normal" to hide or show controls. Remember, if you set a "div" or "grid" or any control as visible = false, then it is not rendered and NOT sent to the client side browser. That means any client side js can't hide/show that control since it was never rendered and sent to the browser. If you attempt to turn visible = true with client side code, and even in some cases code behind, then you can often find it does not work, since since the control is not rendered and set to client side browser.